# Get Windows Handle (hWnd) when documents opened

Tags: windows, vba, winapi, hwnd

I'm using Shell.Application in VBA to open Word and PDF documents by looping through a range in excel that holds file paths - there could be up to 10 Word/Pdf docs. This is working fine, sample code is below:

```
Sub OpenFiles()

Dim Shex As Object
Set Shex = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Dim FilePath As String

FilePath = "C:\Users\brian\Documents\My Documents\Test.pdf"

Shex.Open (FilePath)

End Sub
```

When each document is opened I also want to get the Windows handle for it so I can use later position the window. Want to get the handle on opening if possible as seems would be easier than searching after the fact based on window caption as in some methods I have seen.

The code at this link [Experts](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28323487/MoveWindow-in-VBA-in-EXCEL.html) returns the handle of a newly opened notepad via the Process ID. This works for me as described in the link. Could this be adapted to return the handle for an existing document when opened in an already open application (ex. Word). Or is there another way?

Comment: In general, no, this cannot work reliably.  Programs like Word and Adobe Reader are single-instance processes.  They are very large programs so instead of starting a process for each single document, the 2nd and subsequent instances ask the 1st instance to open the document.  So the process quits very quickly again and the process ID is useless.   The only good advice is to not do this.

Comment: Thanks, helpful to understand

Comment: Do you want the handle to the outer Word/Excel window? Or do you want the handle to the inner window which is hosting the document? As Hans pointed out, documents may be hosted in a single process (Word uses a single process, Excel allows multiple processes, etc). If you don't expect a separate process per document, and if you just want the HWND of the outer window, it should be easy enough. If you want the HWND of the individual document window (contained in the outer window), that's a little harder but not impossible.

Comment: Looking for the handle for the windows hosting individual documents. From what I have read maybe use FindWindow api using the window caption, which is also the filename - I will have that.